# Perl - Dynamic/relative File Path - Website

Tags: file, perl, path, relative-path

I am building a website using perl etc and i am trying to open a file and print the contents of it on the site however i can't seem to make it work when using a relative file path...

```
    # Load our header.html template file
open (HEADER, "/xampp/htdocs/website/template/header.html") or die "Can't find header.html - check path...";
print (<HEADER>);
```

That works

However, I would prefer it if I could do something like this:

```
# Load our header.html template file
open (HEADER, "/template/header.html") or die "Can't find header.html - check path...";
print (<HEADER>);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your full path is

```
/xampp/htdocs/website/template/header.html
```

And you're currently in `/xampp/htdocs/website` (this is where your script is located, or is `chdir`ed to), then you can just use the relative path:

```
template/header.html
```

For example

```
open my $fh, "<", "template/header.html" or die $!;
print <$fh>;
```

Note the use of three-argument `open` with a lexical file handle, as well as including the error `$!` in your die statement.

Comment: This is just a roundabout way of saying `template/header.html` is the relative path. Why do you require 1000 characters to say so?

Comment: @ktm5124 You should not take corrections personally, son. So, I was your first downvote eh? I guess I should feel honoured.

Comment: @ktm5124 None whatsoever. I've got a few downvotes to spare now that my rep is not an even 5 or 0. I might even give you one or two. :)

Answer (score 1):

`/template/header.html` is not a relative file path. Try `./template/header.html`

Comment: `./template/header.html` is just a roundabout way of writing `template/header.html`.